# Native Javascript API for SignalR client

Tags: javascript, signalr

As I know, the client-side library for SignalR is based on jQuery and this is a bad approach because I don't need any JavaScript framework in my application but I have to include jQuery to make the SignalR API work.

I want know is there any alternative way/library for connecting to SignalR via JavaScript (without any framework)?

Comment: refactoring the SignalR yourself, perhaps... but that would be silly. jQuery is just a lib, written in JavaScript, so even if you end up rewriting SingalR, you'll find yourself writing about half the code that makes up jQuery... Or, if you _really_ want to reinvent the wheel, you can always write your own SignalR counterpart in JS, cherry-picking only those features you actually want to use

Comment: I know that but I really don't need to use jQuery.

Comment: I got that, but if you're using a lib, that relies on jQuery, you'll have to include it, even if your other scripts don't use it. jQuery can be included, that doesn't mean that you have to use it all the time. Just avoid conflicting varnames (like `$` or `jQuery`) in the global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq
SignalR uses different protocols/methods for the best as possible user experience. If the server and the browser support WebSocket it's going to use this protocol. If you are sure that your clients' browsers are new enough to support WebSockets than you can skip the JS framework and use directly WebSockets. The client will be with best experience and you won't need third-parties.

Here you can read how to use the websocket protocol via JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets.

Comment: Hey Mikno, ~50% of users uses Internet Explorer 6! That's my problem. I can't skip the JavaScript library.

Comment: If this is your case I don't see how you can escape from jQuery.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani: IE6 is __DEAD__, not even MS support it anymore! if 50% of users are still using IE6, than your users are either cavemen or imaginary... sorry mate

Comment: If he's building his application for the Chinese market probably about 20% will use IE6 (http://www.ie6countdown.com/). Unfortunately many state institutions (universities, hospitals, administration...) still use IE6 too...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Exactly they are cavemen, LOL!

Comment: A number of institutions in the UK (including at least one major auto maker's sales chain, and a few hospital trusts I can think of) are still on IE6, locked down by admins with no option to upgrade. As a browser, it should be dead, but it has a kind of afterlife...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own client based on the SignalR client that doesn't have references to jQuery.

Comment: `doesn't have references to javascript`? You mean `jQuery`?

Comment: Yes I meant jQuery.
SignalR's javascript client depends on jQuery as several other people have told you on this thread. If you don't want that dependency then you have to rewrite the client. It's not much more complicated than that.